# Is it possible to build a native-styled toggle button in HTML/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to affect the "pressed" style of a native HTML `<input type="button">` to appear pressed, such that I could implement a toggle button using native styled buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is, unfortunately, no.

There's no way to affect the native style of a button to appear pressed.

Comment: Darn. I guess I will have to find a nice looking non-native one then.

Comment: That might be better anyway, because then you'll be able to ensure consistency across browsers and platforms. I recommend you check out Twitter Bootstrap; it has button components that should do what you're after.

Comment: you may want to resort to using a checkbox and styling its label like a button:

http://jsfiddle.net/UBpVF/2